# Handling Multiple dependent drop down lists in a form using Django and jquery

Tags: jquery, django

I want to create a form with 4 drop down list in which two of them are dependent on the other two, example i have a country and city drop list in which the city is dependent on the country i.e. when a country is selected only cities in that country will show in the city drop down and its working perfectly but my department and unit are not working as expected. I wand same for my department and units, if a department is selected only units in that department should show. I want to implement this in one form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete='off' class="mt-3" novalidate id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cities' %}" data-units-url="{% url 'ajax_load_units' %}">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">{{ form.country|as_crispy_field}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{ form.city|as_crispy_field}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{ form.department|as_crispy_field}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{ form.unit|as_crispy_field}}</div> 
    </div>
 <script>
    $("#id_country").change(function () {
        const url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");  
        const countryId = $(this).val();  

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                'country_id': countryId 
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                $("#id_city").html(data); 
                });
            }
        });

    });

    $("#id_department").change(function () {
        const url = $("#personForm").attr("data-units-url");
        const departmentId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url, 
            data: {
                'department_id': departmentId 
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);  
                $("#id_unit").html(data);  
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```